# build a string using checkbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox

can anybody show me how to build a string using checkbox. what would be the best way to do this.

for example i have 4 checkbox's each with its own value (valueA, valueB, valueC, valueD)
the thing is i want to display each result in different lines.

result if B & C is selected :

valueB 
valueC

and how would i display this again if i saved this into a database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a StringBuilder to build the string, and append Environment.NewLine each time you append:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (CheckBox cb in checkboxes)
{
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(cb.Text); // Or whatever

        // Alternatively:
        // builder.Append(cb.Text);
        // builder.Append(Environment.NewLine); // Or a different line ending
    }
}
// Call Trim if you want to remove the trailing newline
string result = builder.ToString();
```

To display it again, you'd have to split the string into lines, and check each checkbox to see whether its value is in the collection.

Comment: @Jon - Why would you do the two appends rather than AppendLine(cb.Text)?

Comment: Due to failing to remember AppendLine - edited appropriately :)

Comment: (Having said which, it may be sensible to do two appends if you need a specific newline representation instead of "whatever's the default for this platform. Probably not an issue if you're always running on Windows though.)

Comment: Good, as long as you didn't know something that I didn't :) (Although, that is just a given to be honest!)

Comment: i don't get AppendLine (probably because im using vs2003) can u show the example using the two appends.

Comment: @Adyt: Added the alternative code back in. I hope you're campaigning to get up to VS2008 :)

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-code:

```
For each checkbox in the target list of controls
    append value and a newline character to a temporary string variable
output temporary string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"if I saved this into a database" ?
```

You'll need to be a bit more specific with your homework assignments if you're actually going to receive any help here ...

**Edit:** ok, it *might* not be homework but it certainly read like it - after all, manipulating a GUI to generate a view of the user's choices is Interfaces 101 - and even it wasn't it was a terrible question without enough detail to have any chance of getting a decent answer.

Comment: @Unsliced: "without enough detail to have any chance of getting a decent answer" - what part of the question did my answer not cover? Yes, more detail would have been nice, but it really wasn't "terrible".